How to plot each bar with different color?
I've already tried some different approaches to this one but none have worked so far and I cannot identify what is the problem with my plot.
I'm trying to color bars "Relevant" and "Non-relevant" with one color, bars "Promote coverage" and "Don't promote coverage" with a second color and the bar "Novel Total" with a third color.
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

%Import for graphics plot
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm, compat=1.8, grid style={dashed}}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & carTC \\
    1        & 76    \\
    2        & 29    \\
    3        & 19    \\
    4        & 10    \\
    5        & 22    \\
    6        & 7     \\
}\mydata

\hbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
                no markers,
                ybar stacked,
                ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
                axis lines* = left,
                width=1.1\linewidth,
                height=.2\textwidth,
                xtick=data,
                major tick length = 0pt,
                xticklabels = {
                    Total,
                    Novel Total,
                    Promotes Coverage,
                    Don't Promote Coverage,
                    Relevant,
                    Non-Relevant
                },
                xticklabel style = { font=\scriptsize, text width=1cm, align=center },
                ytick = \empty,
                y axis line style = {opacity=0},
                ylabel = number of TC,
                ylabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
                axis on top
            ]
            \addplot table[
                x=interval,
                y=carTC
            ]{\mydata};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


Like this:

One way is insert addplot for each desired bar color with domain restricted to table ranges for this colors  as follows:
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, grid style={dashed}}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    x   &   y   \\
    1   &   76  \\
    2   &   29  \\
    3   &   19  \\
    4   &   10  \\
    5   &   22  \\
    6   &   7   \\
}\mydata

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=96mm,
        axis lines*=left,
        y axis line style = {opacity=0},
enlarge x limits={0.1}, % <---       %
no markers,
        ybar =-4mm,
   bar width = 4mm,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
        xtick={1,2,...,6},
        xticklabels = {
            Total,
            Novel Total,
            Promotes Coverage,
            Don't Promote Coverage,
            Relevant,
            Non-Relevant
        },
        ticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize, text width=12mm, align=center },
        ytick = \empty,
        ylabel = number of TC,
        ylabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
        axis on top
    ]
\addplot + [restrict x to domain=1:2] table  {\mydata};
\addplot + [restrict x to domain=3:4] table  {\mydata};
\addplot + [restrict x to domain=5:6] table  {\mydata};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

